# Data view with parameters in Datazen

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, dashboard, datazen-server

I am designing a dashboard with Datazen. I need to define data view with parameters. Where statement of mdx query as follows

```
where (
 STRTOMEMBER("[X].[X NAME].[" + {{ @XParam }} + "]"), 
 STRTOMEMBER("[Y].[Y NAME].[" + {{ @YParam}} + "]")
)
```

and I defined @XParam and @YParam. My query works when I go next step and get result as expected. But problem occurs when data view added from Datazen Designer to build charts. How can I solve this problem?

Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. 
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding.put_Path(PropertyPath value) 
   at ComponentArt.WinRT.DataVisualization.DataGrids.GridView.GenerateColumn(String name, String bindingPath, Type type)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
where (
 STRTOMEMBER("[X].[X NAME].[" + '{{ @XParam }}' + "]"), 
 STRTOMEMBER("[Y].[Y NAME].[" + '{{ @YParam }}' + "]")
)
```

You missed single quotes and the last space in the second param.

Comment: what will happen is @XParam is null? is there anyway to allow null to be used as @XParam?

Comment: @whytheg null check is required, something like " IIF( ISEMPTY ({{ @X  }} ), "", {{ @X }} ) " should work.